# Regular expression to match string not containing " " "?

Tags: asp.net, regex, match

Input:

```
<img alt="sample" src="/blabla.jpg" /><script type="text/javascript"
src="/blabla.js" /><script type="text/javascript"> var link =
"/pdf/sample.pdf"; </script>
```

Output:

```
"/blabla.jpg", "/blabla.js", "/pdf/sample.pdf" etc.
```

I want to select by file source extension(jpg, pdf, png etc) in all string(html output). How can I make this? Help please

EDIT : My regex pattern is: `" \".+?(\.js|\.jpg)\" "`. But doesn't work correctly. Output is: `"alt="sample" src="/blabla.jpg""`. I want to `"/blabla.jpg"`

Comment: show your code or something which you've tried.

Comment: My regex pattern is: "  \".+?(\.js|\.jpg)\"  ".
But doesn't work correctly. Output is: "alt="sample" src="/blabla.jpg"". I want to "/blabla.jpg"

Comment: I want add link to all matches with Asp.NET.(Sample: "http://link.com/pdf/sample.pdf")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"[^"]*?\.(?:jpg|pdf|js)"
```

Try this.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/bC8aZ4/18